# how to fix width of button for mobile view

Tags: html, css

I am using a CSS button code, but I found some problem in doing it. I want that the width of my button should get fixed for the mobile view but it should be auto for the window. how can I do it, please help? Or it should be auto placed in the center. I am using this code. I am using CSS like this.

CSS code :

```
.button1 
{
    border: 2px solid rgb(0, 0, 0);
    box-sizing: inherit; 
    background-color: #ffffff; 
    margin-right: 1.7px; 
    color: black; 
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: 980;
    padding: 6px 42px;
    text-align: center;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
    width: 96.6px;
    text-decoration: none;
    line-height: 22px; 
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: domine;
    display: inline-table;
}

.button2 
{ 
    border: 2px solid rgb(255, 87, 51);
    background-color: #FF5733;
    box-sizing: inherit;
    margin-right: 1.7px; 
    color: white; 
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: 980;
    padding: 6px 42px;
    text-align: center;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
    width: 96.6px;
    text-decoration: none;
    line-height: 22px; 
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: domine;
    display: inline-table;
}

.button2 a:link, .button2 a:visited 
{
    background-color: #FF5733;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.button2 a:hover, .button2 a:active 
{
    background-color: #FF5733;
    color:#000000;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 680px) and (min-width:0px)
{
    .button2 { padding: 6px 32px;width: 85px;display: inline-table;max-height:80px;}
    .button1 { padding: 6px 32px;width: 85px;max-height:88px;}
}
```

HTML code:

```
<button class="button button1">
    BUY NOW
</button>
<button class="button button2">
    DETALS
</button>
```

Comment: what you are trying to achieve

Comment: I want the button I am using(code above in question) will have a fixed width when anyone watches using the Mobile view. i.e its height can increase but not width. and when it comes to desktop view the width of button auto increases decreased according to content in it. please suggest what changes I should do in my button css

Answer (score 0):

For a start, change the button display from `inline-table` to `inline-block`